# what's the difference in position declaring variable in xilinx?

Tags: verilog, xilinx, hdl

I'm a beginner writing verilog via xilinx.

I have learned port declarations must be like below

```
module mealy(
  nReset,
  clk,
  in,
  out
);

  input  nReset;
  input  clk;
  input  in;
  output out;
endmodule
```

When I use xilinx, it has default option to set variable, it appears like this:

```
module mealy(
  input  nReset,
  input  clk,
  input  in,
  output out
);

endmodule
```

Sometimes, when I use second way, it generates an error. What is the difference between two styles?

---

A secondary issue, when declaring outputs as `reg`s the first style works correctly ie

```
module mealy(
  in,
  out
 );

  output out;
  input  in;
  reg    out;
endmodule
```

When using the second style, It generates an error stating that you can't declare twice.

```
module mealy(
  input  in,
  output out
);
  reg out;
endmodule
```

What is the matter? I am just beginner I don't know exactly why I must declare 'reg'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verilog 1995 often referred to as verilog-95 (IEEE 1364-1995), use to have port declarations separated from directions and separate again from reg types.

Since Verilog 2001 (IEEE 1364-2001) the more compact version can be used.

If your tools are only 95 standard compliant they will error on code intended for 2001 or later.

When using the new port declaration, including direction you should also declare type if not a  wire.

```
module mealy(
  input  in,              // Inputs are implicitly wires (reg would not make sense)
  output     [1:0] out_x, // 2 bit wire type as output
  output reg [1:0] out_y  // 2 Bit reg  type as output
);
endmodule
```

The difference between reg and wire types should be looked up, basically it is a simulation optimisation. If using SystemVerilog they can both be replaced with a `logic` type.

`Wire`s are driven by ports, or assign statements. `reg`s are assigned inside `always` or `initial` blocks. `reg` does **NOT** imply flip-flop.

Comment: thanks Morgan for helping. the another question is why it cannot be declared same way. I added my code for another question. please help for one more question.

Comment: You've asked two questions; you need to give the error message for both. The second error is easy; you can't mix the old and new-style declarations. The first error isn't obvious. You say 'sometimes' it produces an error. When? What's the error? Is `out` a wire? Do you have `default_nettype` set somewhere?

Comment: @EML I think you meant to comment on the question not the answer. The main question was 'what is the difference' not how to make the error go away, in that regard the exact tool error is not as relevant.

Comment: It is by convention to state the output first, then the inputs, followed by the control input. However, for more complex logic, it is okay to make up port order rules of your own to most logically represent the circuit. Always compare the instance against its declaration.